# Writing a powershell command to combine specifically named folders

Tags: windows, powershell

I'm looking for a command that will search through all of the subfolders of my main customer files folder, identify any folders labelled as "Quotes-Tenders" and merge them with the file called "Quotes and Enquiries".

The customer files folder is located Y:\Customer Files and contains 1,285 to search, the search only needs to go one level down.

I have tried the rename command on a test folder however this runs into a conflict error with having two of the same named file.

```
PS C:\Users\Gareth> Get-ChildItem C:\Users\Gareth\Desktop\Test -Recurse -Directory | Where-Objects-Tenders*"} | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.name-replace 'Quotes-Tenders', 'Quotes and Enquiries'}
```

Any help on how to get around this issue would be great.

Comment: Thats quite ambiguous. Merge folders with a file? And a rename shall achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

i propose you this code

```
Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\Gareth\Desktop\Test" -Recurse -Directory | 
    Where Name -like "*Quotes-Tenders*" | 
        sort -Descending {($_.FullName -split '\\').Length } |
            %{
                $newname=Join-Path -Path $_.Parent.FullName -ChildPath $_.Name.Replace('Quotes-Tenders', 'Quotes and Enquiries')
                Rename-Item $_.FullName -NewName $newname
             }
```

For explain:

- List item
- I take all directory tree
- I select with where clause,
- I sort by number of directory section because you can have a diretory
  like this
  'C:\temp\Quotes-Tendres ggg\Quotes-Tendres. ffff'
  and 
  'C:\temp\Quotes-Tendres ggg' in you list, in this case i want rename first 'C:\temp\Quotes-Tendres ggg\Quotes-Tendres. ffff'
- I rename the directory